# How to use e-signature PDF with Python/GoLang?

Tags: go, pdf, e-signature

What is the easiest way to implement Digitally Sign a PDF file through coding? I am mainly looking for Python or Golang guide.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to implement digitally sign a document, you can use UniPDF, their libraries are in Golang and they have many of the use cases implemented as an example. For your specific requirement, please see https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/tree/v3/signatures

You can also signup for free to process 100 documents free every month. Here is the link https://cloud.unidoc.io/#/signup